# Blazor Server hosted on IIS - Mixed content error

Tags: https, hosting, blazor-server-side, iis-10, mixed-content

I created a Blazor Server API.  I am hosting this on IIS on my local PC using HTTPS only with a self generated certificate.  It works a treat.  I created another Blazor Server API, created another website for it in exactly the same way as I did the first, but when I run the new website I get a mixed-content error.  Please don't get bogged down in that, I understand what that means and I have read for about 8 hours on how to fix it.  None of the solutions I came across worked.

So, I published my new API to the working website and voila, it works perfectly.  This leads me to believe that it is something to do with how I have set up the new site on IIS.

So I deleted the "broken" website via IIS, edited my applicationHost.config, duplicating the original working site, made the appropriate changes and fired up IIS again.  Re-published my new API, same problem.

One thing I don't understand is, it fails on a call to 'http://www.mailcontrol.com/http-resources/notification-pages/icons60/error.png', but then displays the image that refers to!!!  Not sure if this is a red herring, as it works fine when published to the original website, reinforcing my initial thought that it must be an IIS setup thing.

Here are the things that are failing:

[image]

All of which exist on the working API/website

Any help gratefully appreciated.

**Edit**

Console log as requested:

```html
    transactions.oracle.local/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://transactions.oracle.local/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://www.mailcontrol.com/http-resources/notification-pages/icons60/error.png'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html
    transactions.oracle.local/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://transactions.oracle.local/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://www.mailcontrol.com/http-resources/notification-pages/2020/notification_page_logo_145x35.png'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html
    Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
    Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
    Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
    Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
    Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
    Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
    transactions.oracle.local/:71 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://transactions.oracle.local/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://www.mailcontrol.com/http-resources/notification-pages/icons60/error.png'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html
    transactions.oracle.local/:71 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://transactions.oracle.local/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://www.mailcontrol.com/http-resources/notification-pages/2020/notification_page_logo_145x35.png'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html
    transactions.oracle.local/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://transactions.oracle.local/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.mailcontrol.com/http-resources/notification-pages/empty.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Please check and provide detailed information about mixed-content errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

(Hangs head in shame)  The mixed content issue was a complete red herring.  Some idiot made a typo in the hosts file...

Sorry to anyone that wasted their time looking at this non-issue.  Valuable lesson for those that follow though..